# How to show alerts when using full_pdf_viewer

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter full_pdf_viewer package to view a pdf before saving. I have a save option which I would like to have a confirmation before saving. However, when I try to render the alert it does not show up. Currently, I have a workaround where I pop the PDFViewerScaffold before showing the alert however this is not the intended behavior. This is the code I currently have

```
class EditorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditorPage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditorPageState createState() => _EditorPageState();
}

class _EditorPageState extends State<EditorPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
    final pdfPath = arguments['pdfPath'];

    return Scaffold(
      body: PDFViewerScaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Document"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                child: Icon(Icons.save),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Enter the title of your notice'),
                          content: Text('This is a test'),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text('Approve'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          path: pdfPath),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a key to your Scaffold:

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

And in your Scaffold:

```
return Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
```

This solve the problem here.

Comment: This did not work for me. I still have the same error after adding the key. @LOfG